# How to show custom Attribute in items invoiced below the SKU in magento2.2.0?

Tags: magento2, attributes, invoice

> I want to show Custom Attribute in items invoiced below the SKU in
>   magento2.2.0?

Please refer below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What is the attribute value you want to show? Also does this value saved somewhere in order item table or it should come from Product?

Comment: The custom attribute is created from backend. its value is 5

Comment: Do you want to show this only on invoice items?

Comment: Please check my answer that will only work for invoice view page.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code. its working perfectly fine. But i want the same logic on Item orders Table, Items to Refund, Invoice History Email, Email Copy of Credit Memo. Thanks:)

Comment: Then you need to modify the name.phtml by overriding the file form module-sales. There is one name.phtml for order, shipment, creditmemo etc. But for email you need to check the other file. I am updating my answer for admin orders, invoices, shipments and creditmemo.

Comment: May i know when will you update the answer.

Comment: Can you check its already updated. For emails you need to find correct file and update.

Comment: In items order table is not reflecting and in credit memos and shipments the SKU itself is being removed.

Comment: Sorry, I have applied wrong vendor name.. Now its coming for credit memos and shipments. But  I am not able to achieve this on sales_order_view.xml

Comment: Hi, everything is working perfectly fine now. can u also please share me how to show custom attribute on edit page of credit memos, shipment and invoice. and also share me the documentation for referring this as I am completely new to Magento which will be very helpful to me. And thank you so much for your support you just saved my day. Thanks:)

Comment: Add new question, I ll definitely help you.

Comment: I have posted a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a module with name STech_Invoiceattribute by following below steps:

**Step 1:** Create **registration.php** under

> app/code/STech/Invoiceattribute/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Invoiceattribute',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:** Create **module.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Invoiceattribute/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Invoiceattribute" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:** Create **sales_order_view.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Invoiceattribute/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name" template="STech_Invoiceattribute::items/column/name.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 4:** Create **sales_order_invoice_view.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Invoiceattribute/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name" template="STech_Invoiceattribute::items/column/name.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 5:** Create **adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Invoiceattribute/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name" template="STech_Invoiceattribute::items/column/name.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 6:** Create **sales_order_creditmemo_view.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Invoiceattribute/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name" template="STech_Invoiceattribute::items/column/name.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 7:** Create **name.phtml** under

> app/code/STech/Invoiceattribute/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml

```
<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>
    <div id="order_item_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>_title"
         class="product-title">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="product-sku-block">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('SKU') ?>:</span> <?= implode('<br />', $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->splitSku($block->escapeHtml($block->getSku()))) ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($block->getOrderOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getOrderOptions() as $_option): ?>
                <dt><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['label'] ?>:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $_option = $block->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['value'] ?><?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots = 'dots' . uniqid() ?>"> ...</span><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id = 'id' . uniqid() ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['remainder'] ?></span>
                            <script>
                                require(['prototype'], function() {
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').show();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').show();});
                                });
                            </script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php //Your code starts to show custom attribute value ?>
    <dl class="item-options">
        <dt><?= __('Custom Label') ?>:</dt>
        <dd><?= $_item->getProduct()->getCustom() ?></dd>
    </dl>
    <?php //Your code ends to show custom attribute value ?>
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thats it!. Now run setup upgrade and other required commands and check. Don't forget to replace your attribute code in place of "custom".